# Inclined plane movement of spinneret

Tags: software

Normally 3D printing is done starting at the base level depositing hot plastic upwards.

In order to create bas relief details, can we deposit hot plastic on an available centered cone base any curve design allowing slow hot end /spinneret movement in vertical or inclined planes (instead of pure Z direction) by any user-defined CNC control program with a 3D printer?

[image: Two planters with abstract images of a face]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would have to rewrite the code specifically for the surface you want to print on, so the printer recognizes the base is not flat.

You'd  have to attach an identical pot in exactly the same spot on your printer bed for each print.

For the pots you show, you might try printing just the black design flat, maybe 1 mm thick to keep it flexible, then gluing it to your pot.  Using soft filament would make this easier.

Another option would be a 3D pen.

Or use a cutting machine like a Cricut to cut it in self stick vinyl.  I believe those machines use SVG files.